# Paypal V2 Update Order can I update purchase unit items

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

My application already have a working creation of paypal order and paypal payment capture.

Now, in my system... it is possible the customer will update the cart items (replace order item or change the quantity, etc).

Instead of creating a new order for this, I am thinking of updating the existing paypal order.

In the docs, I can only see `/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount` patchable and not the `order items`.

If I update the amount only.. it will get an error since it does not match with the current/existing order items (price * qty) and total, etc.

To get this right, I also need to update the order items but it seems there is no:
`/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/items`.

What patch path should I use so that I can update the purchase unit order items? If I can update the purchase unit order items and amount... I think it will proceed with the update.

If purchase unit order items is not a patchable field, then I think updating the order will not work.

I will need to cancel this order and create a new one based on the updated/new order details.

If updating purchase unit order items possible (in paypal order)? If yes, what should be the correct path?

TIA

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: no, I read it from somewhere that time that they just recreate a new order instead of updating the old one. This is the approach I did and I just made sure that the invoice number is unique.